# Vue.js: Accessing first item in an array not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to **subscribe** to the first object from the following json array.

```
"data" : [ {
      "registrationNumber" : "1234",
      "vehicleMake" : "B.M.W.",
      "vehicleModel" : "R1100 S",
      "cylinderCapacity" : "1100",
      "typeOfFuel" : "Petrol",
      "colour" : "Blue",
      "dateOfFirstRegistration" : "Wed Feb 18 00:00:00 GMT 2000"
    } ]
```

Here is the **vehicle.js** which is accessing data fine under the previous json structure, which did not use an array to store the object (only ever going to be single).

```
  export function getVehicleEnquiry({ regNumber }) {
  return axios.post(`${API}/VehicleLookup`, {
    fieldname: 'registrationNumber',
    value: regNumber,
  }).then(data => ({
    data: {
      regNumber: data.registrationNumber,
      make: data.vehicleMake,
      model: data.vehicleModel,
      firstRegistered: data.dateOfFirstRegistration,
      capacity: data.cylinderCapacity,
      fuelType: data.typeOfFuel,
      color: data.colour,
    },
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your response contains an array now, the object is not directly accessible. With `[0]` you're referring to the first index of the array, which "contains" the object you're looking for.

Change `data` to `data[0]`:

```
data: {
      regNumber: data[0].registrationNumber,
      make: data[0].vehicleMake,
      model: data[0].vehicleModel,
      firstRegistered: data[0].dateOfFirstRegistration,
      capacity: data[0].cylinderCapacity,
      fuelType: data[0].typeOfFuel,
      color: data[0].colour,
    },
```